# jQuery sortable connected lists not always serializing data

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I am working on connecting various sortable widgets, you can move widgets between lists and order them. The problem is, occasionally serializing will return null, yet dragging the same object again to a different list will return some data.

```
// Handle the sorting of containers
let sortableConf = {
    handle: "> .edit-active-hide .sort-handle",
    items: "> div:not(.edit-active-hide)",
    stop: function (event, ui) {
        let data = $(this).sortable('serialize');

        console.log('data', data);
        data = data + '&parent-id=' + $(this).attr('data-layout-element-parent-id');

        console.log('this', $(this));

        axios.post('/layout/elements/sort', data)
            .then(response => {
                console.log('Response', response);
            })
    },
    start: function (e, ui) {
        ui.placeholder.height(ui.item.height());
    },
    placeholder: "ui-state-highlight"
};

$(".sort-page-containers").sortable(sortableConf);

//Handle widgets, we want to connect with other widget lists for awesomeness
sortableConf.connectWith = '.sort-page-content';

$(".sort-page-content").sortable(sortableConf);
```

3 things can happen

- It can return the correct data
- It can return null
- It sometimes only returns a single id when there are multiple in the list.

Things to note

- Every element has a unique id
- It mostly returns null when moving out of an empty list, for example moving the item to an empty list will return data, but moving it out will return no data, moving it again will return data.